# WebView Cant get onClick event

Tags: android, android-layout, webview

I have an app with a WebView. In the webview the app shows to the user an Internet Page that have a link that launch my app, but in another Activity.
In the html page I was doing something like

```
<a href="my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here"></a>
```

And everything goes fine, but I need to do the same thing with Javascript. So am doing this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function redirect(n){
window.location = n;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="target"  onClick="redirect('my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here')" >Name</button>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing happens.
Am using Android 1.6

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [enable Javascript](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29) for the view? It is disabled by default ([docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)).

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>
<button id="target"  onClick="parent.location='my.special.scheme://other/parameters/here'" >Name</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this. :)